# VBA Excel problem with copying images across all worksheets generated by the function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function, which populates the worksheets for me. One of the elements of this worksheet is copying the image located on the "Frontsheet" worksheet.

My code looks like this:

```
 Function CreateStandardSheet(wkb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
 Set CreateStandardSheet = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
 With CreateStandardSheet
    .Name = SheetName
    .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
    .Columns("M:P").ColumnWidth = 13
    Rows(1).RowHeight = 3
    Rows(49).RowHeight = 3
    
    '--------------------------------2.1 Major working area ------------------------------------------
    With Range("B2:L48")
    .Merge
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
    End With
    '---------------------------------2.2 Logo section -------------------------------------------------
    With Range("M41:P46") '....2.2.1 CLIENT LOGO....
    .Merge
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("ClientLogo").Copy
    CreateStandardSheet.Paste
    
    With CreateStandardSheet.Shapes("ClientLogo")
    .Top = 570
    .Left = 600
    .Width = 170
    End With
```

At the following line:

```
 Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("ClientLogo").Copy
```

I have an error:

**Compile error: Expected variable or procedure, not module.**

I am wondering where the problem might be and why can't I populate the images across all the worksheets created by this function.

Comment: Maybe you should start by fixing the missing `End With`s and propper indenting.

Comment: `Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("ClientLogo").Copy` can't raise any error with `OERN` in your code. Pls avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.

Comment: All the End With are alright. The problemmight be in a different place somewhere

Comment: If all the End With are alright then you have not posted all the code into your question

Comment: Do you have a module names `Worksheets`?

Comment: Yhhyyy Yes I have modules  like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Qualify Your Objects (Ranges and Worksheets)

```vb
Function CreateStandardSheet(ByVal wkb As Workbook, ByVal SheetName As String) As Worksheet
    
    Dim sh As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = wkb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A sheet named """ & sh.Name & """ already exists " _
            & "in workbook """ & wkb.Name & """!", vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set CreateStandardSheet = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
    
    With CreateStandardSheet

        .Name = SheetName
        .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
        .Columns("M:P").ColumnWidth = 13
        .Rows(1).RowHeight = 3
        .Rows(49).RowHeight = 3
        '--------------------------------2.1 Major working area ------------------------------------------
        With .Range("B2:L48")
            .Merge
            .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
        End With
        '---------------------------------2.2 Logo section -------------------------------------------------
        With .Range("M41:P46") '....2.2.1 CLIENT LOGO....
            .Merge
            .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
        End With
        
        wkb.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("ClientLogo").Copy
        .Paste
        
        With .Shapes("ClientLogo")
            .Top = 570
            .Left = 600
            .Width = 170
        End With
        ' Missing code?
    End With
    ' Missing code?

End Function
```